# extra template argument causes overload ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to extract details of a function template as a template argument.

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct Generator
{
    typedef int type;
    int operator()(int i) const { return i; }
};

// old functions
template <
    typename... Args,
    typename... FArgs>
std::tuple<Args...> g(
    std::tuple<Args...> & a,
    FArgs&&... fargs)
{
    return std::make_tuple( (Generator<Args>()(fargs...))... );
}

template <
    typename Arg,
    typename... FArgs>
std::tuple<Arg> g(
    std::tuple<Arg> & a,
    FArgs&&... fargs)
{
    return std::make_tuple( (Generator<Arg>()(std::forward<FArgs>(fargs)...)) );
}

// new functions
template <
    template <typename T> class F,
    typename... Args,
    typename... FArgs>
std::tuple<Args...> h(
    std::tuple<Args...> & a,
    FArgs&&... fargs)
{
    return std::make_tuple( (F<Args>()(fargs...))... );
}

template <
    template <typename> class F,
    typename Arg,
    typename... FArgs>
std::tuple<Arg> h(
    std::tuple<Arg> & a,
    FArgs&&... fargs)
{
    return std::make_tuple( (F<Arg>()(std::forward<FArgs>(fargs)...)) );
}

int main()
{
    auto t = std::make_tuple( 1 );
    auto y = g(t, 2);
    auto z = h<Generator>(t, 2);  // ERROR
}
```

It compiles fine with clang, but using gcc (4.9, 5.3, and 6.2) I get the following error:

```
% g++ --std=c++11 test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:56:28: error: call of overloaded ‘h(std::tuple<int>&, int)’ is ambiguous
  auto z = h<Generator>(t, 2);
                            ^
test.cc:34:21: note: candidate: std::tuple<_Elements ...> h(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&, FArgs&& ...) [with F = Generator; Args = {int}; FArgs = {int}]
 std::tuple<Args...> h(
                     ^
test.cc:45:17: note: candidate: std::tuple<Arg> h(std::tuple<Arg>&, FArgs&& ...) [with F = Generator; Arg = int; FArgs = {int}]
 std::tuple<Arg> h(
```

Should this be ambiguous? If so, why isn't the call to `g` also ambiguous?

Comment: Something does not add up: `Generator<Args>()(fargs...)`. The `operator()` member function in `Generator` always takes one parameter. How do you expect to use it with a parameter pack containing ten parameters?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This was a stripped down version of my actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define your new functions as:

```
template <
    template <typename T> class F,
    typename... Args,
    typename... FArgs>
std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args)>1), std::tuple<Args...>> h(
    std::tuple<Args...> & a,
    FArgs&&... fargs)
{
    return std::make_tuple( (F<Args>()(fargs...))... );
}

template <
    template <typename> class F,
    typename Arg,
    typename... FArgs>
std::tuple<Arg> h(
        std::tuple<Arg> & a,
        FArgs&&... fargs)
{
    return std::make_tuple( (F<Arg>()(std::forward<FArgs>(fargs)...)) );
}
```

This will allow to disambiguate and actually your code compiles.

In fact, both the implementations of `h` take a `tuple` and an `int` as an argument and a `tuple` with only one type is valid for both of them.
The sfinae expression (see the `enable_if_t`) forces to choose the second implementation of `h` in that case, the first one for all the others.

Comment: I ended up using this as a workaround. I was hoping for a more definitive answer about whether it was a bug in gcc or if it actually is ambiguous.

Comment: I said it in the answer, it is not a bug in GCC, it was actually ambiguous. The code in the answer explains how to disambiguate it. That's all.

Comment: that's true, but doesn't explain why g isn't just as ambiguous.

Comment: @pelletjl I'm not at the pc right now, I'll try to give you more details later.